# Problem in SQLWorkBench when I trying to open the Diagram EER I can't see the tools and other things

Tags: mysql, sql-server, workbench

when I go to
**SQL WorkBench** >> **File** >> **New Model**
this is what I get

this is on my **teacher** **screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcC89.jpg)

and this is on **my** **screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWRKl.png)

there is some images hide like **Add diagram**

and when I click in the same place on the **Add Diagram**
I got this

this is on my **teacher screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZMLh.jpg)

and this is on **my screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oRwc.png)

I can't see the tools

how I can solve this problem

I deleted the program
and download it again
but its still Existing

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL server? It's a completely different product to mysql

Comment: I didn’t even know that